# como colorer un boton de varios colores?

Tags: javascript, html, vuetify

hola se puede colorear un boton con varios colores? seria para hacer un boton con 4 colores en vez de uno solo

```
<v-btn
@click="funcion()"
color="primary"
>
Colorear tabla
</v-btn>
```

el codigo es solo de ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usando la propiedad Gradient,
por ejemplo

```
to top, #7B1FA2, #E1BEE7,#AA7652,#FF7807
```

el Resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si eso mismo era lo que queria lograr muchas gracias @Jose Manuel Encarnacion Rendon

Comment: por nada, estamos para ayudarnos